# Opening Adobe Indesign on other user's computer puts objects in groups

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

We use ExtendScript with Adobe Indesign. Part of the workflow is to use a InDesign document as a template. The ExtendScript open a InDesign document, and replaces some text and images, and saves a pdf.

e.g. part of the code.

```
app.activeDocument.textFrames.item('design.name').contents= "John Doe"
```

Most items in the document are named. (done by modifying the names of the element in the Layer Toolbar)
[image: Example of a text element in the Layers toolbar]

Now when another user opens this document and saves it, it will place the elements in a group automatically.
[image: Example of a text element within group in the Layers toolbar]

This causes the script to stop working because the reference of `textFrames.item('design.name')` isn't available anymore.

How to handle this issue? because I don't want to manually move the elements out of the group after our designer has changed the InDesign document. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this error with my InDesign (CC2018, Mac). I could try to open your file if you provide it.

Comment: You need to provide more info. What are the version of InDesign crating the template and the one which run the script? I only saw something similar when use LDML files when open file with older version of InDesign. Another thing to check - what is the script the user is running - it might be a different version of the script

Comment: @YuriKhristich I can't reproduce the issue anymore. Not 100% sure if designer used exact same file or an already modified copy.